# How to get UIModalPresentationPageSheet frame after traitCollectionDidChange

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitraitcollection

Some strange behavior occurs when I use multi tasking and try to get frame of the `UIViewController`.

I use:

```
- (void)traitCollectionDidChange:(UITraitCollection *)previousTraitCollection
```

To update frame of the views after we change application trait collection.

How I mesure width:

```
CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame)
```

Problem is that in very beginning width of the `UIViewController` in landscape mode is 1024px. After changing of the trait collection, size of the `UIViewController` is predictable is changing. But when I return to initial state width should be 1024px but it is 694px.